# Display the names of customers who ordered the same set of products as customers from Brazil

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

Microsoft Sql Server 2017, database Northwind.

Hello everyone, I'm still trying to do these question in sql server, but I stacked and I don't know how to do this. Please give me some tip, how to bite it :P

```
select *     
from

(select companyname, products.productid, productname,[Order Details].OrderID
    from [order details], orders, customers, products
    where [order details].orderid=orders.orderid AND
          orders.customerid=customers.customerid AND
          [order details].productid=products.productid) c1
    inner join
    (select companyname, products.productid, productname, [Order Details].OrderID
    from [order details], orders, customers, products
    where [order details].orderid=orders.orderid AND
          orders.customerid=customers.customerid AND
          [order details].productid=products.productid  AND
          Customers.Country='Brazil') c2
          on c1.productId=c2.productId and c1.productname=c2.productname
```

Comment: You should start by learning ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins For the question at hand I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, I will read the link :) I have to display customers who ordered the same set of products, as customers from Brazil, so i have to compare in some way two selects and display the company names.

Comment: I'd suggest using some aliasing too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether or not customers in Brazil should be *excluded* from the resulting data, but to point you in the right direction, consider the following query:

```
select c.*
from
    (
        select distinct o.productid
        from [order details] o inner join customers c
        on o.customerid = c.customerid
        where c.country = 'Brazil'
    ) p
    inner join [order details] o on p.productid = o.productid
    inner join customers c on o.customerid = c.customerid
```

Here, the nested selection obtains a distinct set of products purchased by customers in Brazil. The result of this selection is then joined to your `order details` table to obtain all customers who have purchased such products (this will include the Brazilians).